# Terrible performance on Iris dataset using deeplearning4j

Tags: java, scala, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm experimenting `deeplearning4j`, by following some of their tutorials. The iris dataset is well known, and by using Weka (either with a RandomForest or a MultilayerPerceptron), I can easily get the F-measure to reach almost 1 (0.97 in the following example):

```
             TP Rate  FP Rate  Precision  Recall   F-Measure  MCC      ROC Area  PRC Area  Class
              1.000    0.000    1.000      1.000    1.000      1.000    1.000     1.000     Iris-setosa
              0.960    0.020    0.960      0.960    0.960      0.940    0.996     0.993     Iris-versicolor
              0.960    0.020    0.960      0.960    0.960      0.940    0.996     0.993     Iris-virginica Weighted 
      Avg.    0.973    0.013    0.973      0.973    0.973      0.960    0.998     0.995
```

I'm not being so successful with `deeplearning4j`:

```
Examples labeled as 0 classified by model as 0: 4 times
Examples labeled as 1 classified by model as 0: 12 times
Examples labeled as 2 classified by model as 0: 14 times

Warning: class 1 was never predicted by the model. This class was excluded from the average precision
Warning: class 2 was never predicted by the model. This class was excluded from the average precision

Accuracy:  0.1333  Precision: 0.1333  Recall:    0.3333  F1 Score: 0.1905
```

Here's the code (in Scala) I'm using:

```
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.impl.IrisDataSetIterator
import org.deeplearning4j.eval.Evaluation
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.api.{Layer, OptimizationAlgorithm}
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.{Updater, NeuralNetConfiguration}
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.layers.{OutputLayer, RBM}
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.weights.WeightInit
import org.deeplearning4j.ui.weights.HistogramIterationListener
import org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j
import org.nd4j.linalg.lossfunctions.LossFunctions

object Main extends App {
  Nd4j.MAX_SLICES_TO_PRINT = -1
  Nd4j.MAX_ELEMENTS_PER_SLICE = -1
  Nd4j.ENFORCE_NUMERICAL_STABILITY = true

  val inputNum = 4
  var outputNum = 3
  var numSamples = 150
  var batchSize = 150
  var iterations = 1000
  var seed = 321
  var listenerFreq = iterations/5
  val learningRate = 1e-6

  println("Load data....")

  val iter = new IrisDataSetIterator(batchSize, numSamples)
  val iris = iter.next()
  iris.shuffle()
  iris.normalizeZeroMeanZeroUnitVariance()

  val testAndTrain = iris.splitTestAndTrain(0.80)
  val train = testAndTrain.getTrain
  val test = testAndTrain.getTest

  println("Build model....")

  val RMSE_XENT = LossFunctions.LossFunction.RMSE_XENT

  val conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
    .seed(seed)
    .iterations(iterations)
    .learningRate(learningRate)
    .l1(1e-1).regularization(true).l2(2e-4)
    .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.CONJUGATE_GRADIENT)
    .useDropConnect(true)
    .list(2)
    .layer(0, new RBM.Builder(RBM.HiddenUnit.RECTIFIED, RBM.VisibleUnit.GAUSSIAN)
      .nIn(inputNum).nOut(3).k(1).activation("relu").weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER).lossFunction(RMSE_XENT)
      .updater(Updater.ADAGRAD).dropOut(0.5)
      .build())
    .layer(1, new OutputLayer.Builder(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MCXENT)
      .nIn(3).nOut(outputNum).activation("softmax").build())
    .build()

  val model = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf)
  model.init()
  model.setListeners(new HistogramIterationListener(listenerFreq))

  println("Train model....")
  model.fit(train.getFeatureMatrix)

  println("Evaluate model....")
  val eval = new Evaluation(outputNum)
  val output = model.output(test.getFeatureMatrix, Layer.TrainingMode.TEST)

  (0 until output.rows()).foreach { i =>
    val actual = train.getLabels.getRow(i).toString.trim()
    val predicted = output.getRow(i).toString.trim()
    println("actual " + actual + " vs predicted " + predicted)
  }

  eval.eval(test.getLabels, output)
  println(eval.stats())
}
```

Comment: RBMs only work well on specific distributions of your input data (e.g. images and maybe recommendations). Also your RBM has very little expressibility, you only have three units which is probably not enough to capture anything from the input distribution. Here's an interesting explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641485/gaussian-rbm-fails-on-a-trivial-example I'd probably start with fully connected layers like in Weka and go from there.

Comment: Hello Hugo, dl4j developers suggest to ask questions on gitter from official site.

Answer (score 1):

You can try removing regularization:

> .l1(1e-1).regularization(true).l2(2e-4)
>   Here are my code:

```
public MultiLayerNetwork buildModel() {
    int lowerSize = featureSize;
    List<DenseLayer> hiddenLayers = new ArrayList<DenseLayer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < hiddenLayersDim.length; i++) {
        int higherSize = hiddenLayersDim[i];
        hiddenLayers.add(new DenseLayer.Builder().nIn(lowerSize).nOut(higherSize)
                .activation(activationType).weightInit(weightInit).build());
        lowerSize = higherSize;
    }
    NeuralNetConfiguration.ListBuilder listBuilder = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .seed(seed)
            .iterations(iterations)
            .optimizationAlgo(algorithm)
            .learningRate(learningRate)
            .updater(updater)
            .list();
    int layerCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hiddenLayers.size(); i++) {
        listBuilder.layer(layerCount, hiddenLayers.get(i));
        layerCount += 1;
    }
    listBuilder.layer(layerCount, new OutputLayer.Builder(lossFunction)
            .weightInit(weightInit)
            .activation("softmax")
            .nIn(lowerSize).nOut(labelSize).build());
    MultiLayerConfiguration conf = listBuilder.pretrain(false).backprop(true).build();
    MultiLayerNetwork net = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
    net.init();
    net.setListeners(new ScoreIterationListener(1));
    this.net = net;
    return net;
}
```